# Clickon the item in RecyclerView and return the URL of the selected item

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm having trouble implementing this in code
I wanted something that when I clicked on the item I get the URL and open a new `Activity` in a `WebView`, thank you already.

Beaches.java

```
package com.novela.minha.novela;

public class Beaches {

public String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public Beaches() {
}

public String url;
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
package com.novela.minha.novela;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Beaches> beaches;

public MyAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Beaches> beaches){
    this.c= c;
    this.beaches=beaches;
}
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card,parent,false);
    MyHolder holder= new MyHolder(v);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nameTxt.setText(beaches.get(position).getName());
    PicassoClient.downloadimg(c, beaches.get(position).getUrl(),holder.img);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return beaches.size();
}
}
```

NoticiasFragment.java

```
package com.novela.minha.novela;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NoticiasFragment extends Fragment {
final static String DB_URL = "https:/myendrendnd.firebaseio.com/";
EditText nameeditText, urleditText;
Button btnsave;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
FirebaseClient firebaseClient;

public NoticiasFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticias, container, false);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    recyclerView =  view.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerNoticias);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient(getActivity(), DB_URL, recyclerView);
    firebaseClient.refreshdata();


    return recyclerView;
}


    private void displayDialog()
{
    Dialog d= new Dialog(getActivity());
    d.setTitle("SaveData");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_layout);
    nameeditText= (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    urleditText=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.urlEditText);
    btnsave= (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firebaseClient.savedata(nameeditText.getText().toString(),urleditText.getText().toString());

            nameeditText.setText("");
            urleditText.setText("");
        }
    });

    d.show();

}


}
```

FirebaseCliete.java

```
package com.example.admin.firebaserecyclerviewexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.novela.minha.novela.Beaches;
import com.novela.minha.novela.MyAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FirebaseClient {

Context c;
String DB_URL;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

Firebase firebase;
ArrayList<Beaches> beaches= new ArrayList<>();
MyAdapter adapter;


public  FirebaseClient(Context c, String DB_URL, RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    this.c= c;
    this.DB_URL= DB_URL;
    this.recyclerView= recyclerView;


    Firebase.setAndroidContext(c);
    firebase=new Firebase(DB_URL);
}

public  void savedata (String name, String texto, String url)
{
    Beaches b= new Beaches();
    b.setName(name);
    b.setUrl(url);
    b.setTexto(texto);

    firebase.child("Beaches").push().setValue(b);


}

public  void refreshdata()
{
    firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getupdates(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            getupdates(dataSnapshot);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
        });
        }

        public void getupdates(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        beaches.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot ds :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        Beaches b= new Beaches();
        b.setName(ds.getValue(Beaches.class).getName());
        b.setTexto(ds.getValue(Beaches.class).getTexto());
        b.setUrl(ds.getValue(Beaches.class).getUrl());
        beaches.add(b);

        }
    if(beaches.size()>0)
    {
        adapter=new MyAdapter(c, beaches);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else
    {
        Toast.makeText(c, "No data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.novela.minha.novela;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText nameeditText,urleditText,textoeditText;
Button btnsave;
com.example.admin.firebaserecyclerviewexample.FirebaseClient firebaseClient;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            displayDialog();


        }
    });

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));


    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}





@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void displayDialog()
{
    Dialog d= new Dialog(this);
    d.setTitle("SaveData");
    d.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_layout);
    nameeditText= (EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    textoeditText= (EditText) d.findViewById(R.id.textoEditText);
    urleditText=(EditText)d.findViewById(R.id.urlEditText);
    btnsave= (Button)d.findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            firebaseClient.savedata(nameeditText.getText().toString(),textoeditText.getText().toString(),urleditText.getText().toString());

            nameeditText.setText("");
            textoeditText.setText("");
            urleditText.setText("");
        }
    });

    d.show();

}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                NoticiasFragment tab1 = new NoticiasFragment();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                ResumoFragment tab2 = new ResumoFragment();
                return tab2;

            case 2:
                MaisFragment tab3 = new MaisFragment();
                return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;

        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

   @Override

    public CharSequence getPageTitle (int position) {

       switch (position) {

           case 0:
               return "NOTICIAS";

           case 1:
               return "RESUMO";
           case 3:
             return   "MAIS";
       }

               return null;



   }
   }
   }
```

MyHolder.Java

```
package com.novela.minha.novela;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView nameTxt, textoTxt;
ImageView img;
public MyHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    nameTxt= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
    img=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    textoTxt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textoTxt);

}
}
```

PicassoClient.java

```
package com.novela.minha.novela;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

public class PicassoClient {

public  static  void downloadimg(Context c, String url, ImageView img)
{
    if (url!=null && url.length()>0)
    {
        Picasso.with(c).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(img);

    }else
    {
        Picasso.with(c).load(R.drawable.placeholder).into(img);
    }
    }
    }
```

I wanted to play the URL of the item sealed in the webview

NewsWebView.java

```
package com.example.minhanovela;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class NewsWebView extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView myWebView;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_web_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pro);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    String id = b.getString("id");
    myWebView.loadUrl(id);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setTitle("Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setTitle(view.getTitle());
        }
    });
           }

            }
```

Comment: Have you considered used Data Binding, with that you can get each items url with a click... let me know if you are considering using data binding

Comment: how could I implement this, I'm new to the world of programming, thank you

Comment: mm ok.. it;s a bit advance so lets better not use that strategy... Have you gotten by now the url or not?

Comment: No, could you implement this in my code?

Comment: Please don't just dump your entire project here. You need to trim it down to the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the issue you're having. Please look into how to create a [mcve].

Comment: sorry, this is my first post here

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView name;
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }

        public void bind(final ContentItem item, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            name.setText(item.name);
            Picasso.with(itemView.getContext()).load(item.imageUrl).into(image);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    //Here's where you get the url from the item like so
                    Log.d("URL", "The url from the item is: " + item.getUrl)
                }
            });
        }
    }`
```

You can see how I integrated Picasso and the click listener there, I use the Log class to output the url , with that  you can use an intent to send the url to the other activity